# Building a RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Problem with regular expression.
I'm creating a textarea with automcompletion
(I use ⇥ for showing you a \n and ␣ for a space character)

one line should look like this

```
1.1␣BMW⇥Red⇥automatic
```

or

```
1.1␣BMW⇥Red
```

if the content of the textarea is the following

```
1.1␣Mercedes.1⇥Blue⇥manual
2␣Chev
```

I would like to get match "Chev"

```
1.1␣Mercedes⇥Blue⇥manual
2␣Chevrolet⇥Gr
```

In this situation I would like to get match "Gr"

Until now I used the following the following expressions.

```
new RegExp('^' +
    '(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*(\\S+)' +  // for the first example
    '\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+)?' +         // for the second example
    '$',
    'm');
```

I think it just worked by accident, but it didn' work in this situation that should also be valid

```
1.1␣BMW⇥Red
2␣Chev
```

(here I would like to get "Chev")

I'd like to use the regex for autocompletion. The result is used to get strings from a array that start with the matched string from the textarea.
The first "column" (Car-Brands) is used to search in a different array then the second one (Colors). The third one is optional an could be ignored. The numbers in the beginning are also not important for matching

I'm really not a regex expert but I tried to work out a solution ... but now I'm anoyed

Thanks for Help

Comment: Do you mean you only need to get the last chunk of non-whitespace chars? `/\S+$/`? Do you really need to validate the input?

Comment: I just tried the edits you made and my answer appears to work. I'm not sure if you intend to match periods in the words though; if not, just remove the `\.` from the expression.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should do what you're wanting: `/[^\s]+$/`. See if this does what you expect:

```
var re = new RegExp(/[^\s]+$/);
var matches = textValue.match(re);
if (matches) {
    // Use matches[0] for your autocomplete since there are no capture groups
}
```

Comment: Also, I wanted to mention a really useful tool for debugging/testing regular expressions: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parentheses around the second part. You think you're making the whole second part optional, but you're only making the last word optional. Even the tabs between them (not \n per your post) aren't optional.

```
new RegExp('^' +
    '(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*(\\S+)' +  // for the first example
    '(\\t(\\S+)\\t(\\S+))?' +         // for the second example
    '$',
    'm');
```